# FastAPI: Internal server error when accessing through OpenAPI docs

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, openapi

I am exposing API using OpenAPI which is developed using FastAPI.

Here is my pydantic model:

```
class ComponentListResponse(BaseModel):
    """
    This model is to list the component

    """
    
    tag_info = ComponentSummaryTagInfoResp 
    heath_status : Optional[str] = Field(alias="healthStatus")
    stage : Optional[str] = Field(alias="stage")
    component_notes: List[dict] =List[ComponentNotes]

class ComponentList(BaseModel):
    """
    This is the base model for component List
    """
    
    data: List[dict] = List[ComponentListResponse]
```

Here is the resource file:

```
from .schema import (
    ComponentListResponse,ComponentList
)
from .service import (
    get_component_list
)

router = APIRouter(prefix="/component", tags=["Component"])

@router.get(
    "/componentList/{component_id}",
    response_description="List component by componentId & CompanyId",
    response_model=ComponentList,
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
)
def get_component_endpoint(
    request: Request,
    component_id: str,
    company_id: str
):
    """
    API handler function for component List API.
    """
    component_list = get_component_list(component_id, company_id)

    print (component_list)
    if component_list:
        return component_list
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail="Component List  not found",
        )
```

I am getting the response properly when I am trying to make a `GET` request from browser.

but when I am trying to access the same  using OpenAPI docs through Swagger UI,  it raises an error (`Internal server error`).

I sense that this is caused due to  `data: List[dict] = List[ComponentListResponse]`.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: It helps if you share the traceback log.

Comment: getting only internal server error .  new in   fasr api not sure about the more

Comment: The first step to debugging this issue is understanding where your application outputs the log.  And if it's not logging properly, you'll need to figure that out.

Comment: And the `tag_info` attribute should probably look like `tag_info: ComponentSummaryTagInfoResp` (with `:` instead of `=`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models are wrongly  defined. The "=" sign should be use to provide default values not type definitions.

Therefore your models should be define as follows:

```
class ComponentListResponse(BaseModel):
    """
    This model is to list the component

    """
    
    tag_info = ComponentSummaryTagInfoResp 
    heath_status : Optional[str] = Field(None, alias="healthStatus")
    stage : Optional[str] = Field(None, alias="stage")
    component_notes: List[ComponentNotes]

class ComponentList(BaseModel):
    """
    This is the base model for component List
    """
    
    data: List[ComponentListResponse]
```

or if you really want to have default values:

```
class ComponentListResponse(BaseModel):
    """
    This model is to list the component

    """
    
    tag_info = ComponentSummaryTagInfoResp 
    heath_status : Optional[str] = Field(None, alias="healthStatus")
    stage : Optional[str] = Field(None, alias="stage")
    component_notes: List[ComponentNotes] = []

class ComponentList(BaseModel):
    """
    This is the base model for component List
    """
    
    data: List[ComponentListResponse] = []
```

Besides don't forget to specify None as a default value for your field that are optional when you are using Field. If you don't put it, FastAPI and Pydantic will expect that those values are always set.